# opera layout problem

Tags: html, css, opera

```
<div id="header">
        <div id="logo">
            <h1><a href="http://lookaroundyou.net">Look Around You</a></h1>
        </div>
        <div id="search">
            <input type="text"/>
            <input type="button" value="search"/>
        </div>
        <div id="horNav">
            <ul class="horNav">
                <li><a class="home" href="#">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a class="submit" href="#">SUBMIT</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
```

this is CSS:

```
#logo{
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
#search{
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
}


#horNav{
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

it works fine in chrome and firefox but in opera it displays div#search under div#logo instead inline on oposite sides??

many thanks

Comment: Code looks good. Should work fine in Opera.

Comment: At least three people can't reproduce your problem. If you want an exact answer, you need to add a test case using [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/) in which your problem occurs.

Comment: Or, add a link to the live page..

Comment: [CLICK](http://lookaroundyou.net)

Answer (score 1):

I can´t reproduce the problem in Opera 11.10, see this [example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeroen/87UCE/), but there are a few possible solutions / things you can try:

1. use `max-width` instead of `width` for `#logo`;
2. change the order of `#logo` and `#search` in the html and remove the `float` and `width` from `#logo`